# Determining the sign of a term

Tags: inequality, convex-analysis

I have a problem in proving the sign of a term. It is as follows:

$$x=\dfrac{1-a}{b_1b_2-a}+1,\qquad y=\dfrac{1-a}{b_1-a}+\dfrac{1-a}{b_2-a},\qquad z=x-y$$
with $0<b_1<1,\quad 0<b_2<1,\quad 0<a<b_1b_2$.

Based on some simulations I have noticed that $z>0$ for several instances of $a$, $b_1$ and $b_2$, but I want to prove it mathematically. What is the simplest method to do this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The following is just a restatement of the problem, but in a standard inequality question form: Prove $$\frac{1}{b-a}+\frac{1}{c-a}<\frac{1}{1-a}+\frac{1}{bc-a}$$ where $0<b<1$, $0<c<1$, and $0<a<bc$.

Comment: (perhaps my above comment would be more appropriate as a title for the question? It seems to be basically what the problem boils down to and is a little more eye-catching)

Comment: By the way, I tried and got nowhere

Comment: Thank you @PeterWoolfitt for your comments. Unfortunately no one has given any answer yet. Do you think of any other website that might also be suitable for posting the question? I tried mathoverflow, but they found it off topic.

Comment: This is the only website I really know of for questions like this. It makes sense that they didn't like it at mathoverflow because the problem is not about research level mathematics.

Comment: This question seems to have a reasonable level of attention, but I could post the reformulation I gave of the problem as a new question, which might streamline the process and draw more interest. Would you mind if I did this? You could also ask this new question yourself.

Comment: @PeterWoolfitt Slowly, slowly. Why re-ask when this has an answer?

Comment: @DanielFischer XD. Looks like there was not much longer to wait

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can write

\begin{align}
x-y &= \frac{1-a}{b_1-a}\cdot \frac{1-a}{b_2-a} - \frac{1-a}{b_1-a} - \frac{1-a}{b_2-a} + 1 + \frac{1-a}{b_1b_2-a} - \frac{1-a}{b_1-a}\cdot \frac{1-a}{b_2-a}\\
&= \biggl(\frac{1-a}{b_1-a} - 1\biggr)\biggl(\frac{1-a}{b_2-a}-1\biggr) + \frac{1-a}{b_1b_2-a} - \frac{1-a}{b_1-a}\cdot \frac{1-a}{b_2-a}.
\end{align}

Now, since $a < b_k < 1$, we have $\frac{1-a}{b_k-a} > 1$, and so the product is strictly positive. Therefore it suffices to see

$$\frac{1-a}{b_1b_2-a} \geqslant \frac{1-a}{b_1-a}\cdot \frac{1-a}{b_2-a}.$$

Cancelling the positive $1-a$ and cross-multiplying, we need to see that

$$(b_1-a)(b_2-a) \geqslant (1-a)(b_1b_2-a).$$

Multiplying both sides out and cancelling the common terms, we need to see that

$$-ab_1 - ab_2 \geqslant -a - ab_1b_2,$$

or

$$a(1-b_1)(1-b_2) \geqslant 0,$$

which is true. Since all transformations we did were equivalences, we have shown that $x-y > 0$, as desired.

Comment: Nice answer! I'm curious - how did you think to try adding and subtracting $$\frac{1-a}{b_1-a}\cdot\frac{1-a}{b_2-a}$$
was their something in the problem that indicated this was a potential approach?

Comment: Pretty much only gut feeling. It looked like it could work, so I gave it a try, and it worked indeed.

Comment: Well, I'm impressed :)

Comment: @DanielFischer thanks a lot, I appreciate that. You made my work easy.